# DISTINCT AND COUNT(*)=1 not working on SQL

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, distinct

I need to show the ID (which is unique in every case) and the name, which is sometimes different. In my code I only want to show the names IF they are unique.

I tried with both distinct and count(*)=1, nothing solves my problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name
FROM person
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING count(name) = 1;
```

The result is still showing the names multiple times

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (MySql, Postgres)?

Comment: You got `DISTINCT` wrong. The way you use it, it applies to the whole row, not just `id`.

Answer (score 2):

If your DBMS supports it, you can use a window function:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS NameCount -- get count of each name
  FROM person
) src
WHERE NameCount = 1
```

If not, you can do:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM person
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT name
  FROM person
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 -- Only get names that occur once
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PARTITION BY id`?

Comment: Why?  You want to group them by `name` and count the number of rows in each group.

Answer (score 2):

By "unique", I assume you mean names that only appear once.  That is not what "distinct" means in SQL; the use of distinct is to remove duplicates (either for counting or in a result set).

If so:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name
FROM person
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```